# Drupal jQuery run script on .resize()

Tags: jquery, drupal, resize

I have the following code that gets the body `height` and writes it to a div that displays as a `table-cell` so the content can be vertically centered on any screen size on `resize`. I've tested this and it works fine.

```
$( window).resize(function() {
    bodyHeight = $('body').outerHeight();
    console.log('bodyHeight =' + bodyHeight);
    $('.table-cell').css('height', bodyHeight +'px');
});
```

Now if I try put it in Drupal using the code below. It doesn't work. jQuery is being called because I can run the script in Drupal but not when I specify to run it on `resize`.

```
jQuery(window).resize(function($) {
    bodyHeight = $('body').outerHeight();
    console.log('bodyHeight =' + bodyHeight);
    $('.table-cell').css('height', bodyHeight +'px');
});
```

Comment: have you written your code in Document.ready?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument in the `resize` method is the `event` object, it's not `jQuery`.

```
jQuery(window).resize(function(e) {
    bodyHeight = $('body').outerHeight();
    console.log('bodyHeight =' + bodyHeight);
    $('.table-cell').height(bodyHeight);
});
```

You can also just use the `.height()` method instead of the `.css()` method.

If you're worried about conflicting `$` variables, wrap it all in this:

```
jQuery(function($){
 // Your window resize here.
 // $ will reference jQuery within this scope
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate, your second suggestion, wrapping it in jQuery(function($) worked. I'll try out the .height() method too. It sounds cleaner than .css() Cheers